# Possible causes of massive amount of logs in logcat? (Background concurrent copying GC freed)

Tags: android, garbage-collection, logcat

What are the possible causes that could cause MASSIVE amounts of logs in logcat between UI automated tests on an android app? When I say massive, I mean thousand of logs like:

```
12-11 18:32:04.071 6857 6868 I zygote : Background concurrent copying GC freed 970(64KB) AllocSpace objects, 14(56MB) LOS objects, 3% free, 148MB/154MB, paused 469us total 167.395ms
12-11 18:32:04.261 6857 6868 I zygote : Background concurrent copying GC freed 5079(271KB) AllocSpace objects, 33(141MB) LOS objects, 6% free, 83MB/89MB, paused 407us total 157.552ms
12-11 18:32:04.625 6857 6868 I zygote : Background concurrent copying GC freed 1618(96KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(28MB) LOS objects, 10% free, 51MB/57MB, paused 6.436ms total 69.100ms
```

Useful info:
- within a suite with, let's say, 4 tests, the first test runs in less than 2 minutes, the second test runs in about 6 minutes, third test takes above 10 minutes to run and the last one takes more than 20 minutes to finish;
- all the tests should take couple of minutes to finish their UI steps; the app is exited after the test finished its UI actions, but until the next test starts, a huge amount of GC logs are flowing in logcat, with nothing else between them;
- this started to happen all of a sudden and I am trying to find a posible root cause for this; I was told this is not an app issue (i don't know if that's the case or not) and I think that something may have changed on the API side.

Any other ideas?
PS: sorry for the lack of specific informations, the app is not mine, so everything else is confidential;

Comment: I do not know how android GC works, but those `concurrent copying` look like some evacuation happening... So it looks like normal GC operations, you allocate a lot => GC is invoked a lot. I guess that testing framework does heavy allocations?

Comment: my question is what may have caused that? all this issue started to happen all of a sudden during a period when no changes were made in the app or in the testing framework

Comment: Obviously I do not know...